# Help needed for $\lim_{x→0}[(a_1^x+..a_n^x)/n]^{(n/x)}$

Tags: limits

I'm running into this question prepping for an exam:

> $\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x}{n})^{\frac{n}{x}}$,while $a_i>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$

Here is how I was trying to solve it:

$$\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x}{n})^{\frac{n}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x-n}{n})^{\frac{n}{x}}\\
& =\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x-n}{n})^{{\frac{n}{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x-n}}\cdot \frac{a_1^x+a_2^x+\cdots+a_n^x-n}{x}}\\
& =e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a_1^x-1+a_2^x-1+\cdots+a_n^x-1}{x}}\\
& =e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\ln{a_1}+x\ln{a_{2}}+\cdots+x\ln{a_{n}}}{x}}\\
& =e^{\lim_{x\to 0}(\ln a_1+\ln a_2+\cdots +\ln a_n)}\\
& =a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n
\end{align}
$$

Can anyone give it a look and let me know if it makes any sense? If not, could you walk me through?

Thanks in advance!
P.S It seems the layout is a bit messed up here with my latex. Symbols seem to be squeezing each other.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Use the following bounds

$$a^x_\min \leq \dfrac{\sum_i^na_i^x}{n}\leq a^x_\max$$

and the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanx ! A new idea!